# Select with innerjoin and dynamic update

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

I created a query in my magento database to find product the have a "New From" dat but no "New To".

```
SELECT 
catalog_product_entity.entity_id,
catalog_product_entity.sku,
a.value as New_From,
b.value as New_To
FROM `catalog_product_entity`
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime as a on a.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id and a.attribute_id = '93'
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime as b on b.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id and b.attribute_id = '94'
WHERE a.value IS NOT NULL AND b.value IS NULL
```

Now what I would like to accomplish since it concerns 500+ items to run a UPDATE statement on this query closing "New To" 1 month after having been opened.

Any ideas how to run that?

So to clarify:

Table 1: (catalog_product_entity)

```
|  entity_id  |  sku  |
|  ---------  |  ---  |
|      1      |  ABC  |
|      2      |  DEF  |
```

Table 2: (catalog_product_entity_datetime)

```
|  id  |  entity_id  |  attribute_id |         value         |
|  --- |  ---------  |  ------------ |         -----         |
|   1  |      1      |       93      |  2013-06-12 00:00:00  |
|   2  |      1      |       94      |  2013-07-12 00:00:00  |
|   3  |      1      |       98      |  Some other attribute |
|   4  |      2      |       93      |  2014-08-20 00:00:00  |
|   5  |      2      |       94      |        NULL           | <- This I want updating
|   6  |      2      |       98      |  Some other attribute |
```

I want to update the NULL values in table 2 with the date from that same table + 1 month. My search returns:

```
|  entity -id  |  sku  |       New_From       |        New_To         |
|  ----------- |  ---  |  ------------------- |  -------------------  |
|       2      |  DEF  |  2014-08-20 00:00:00 |         NULL          |
```

So I would like to write the query that updates that field to the New_From + 1 month.

```
|  entity -id  |  sku  |       New_From       |        New_To         |
|  ----------- |  ---  |  ------------------- |  -------------------  |
|       2      |  DEF  |  2014-08-20 00:00:00 |   2014-09-20 00:00:00 |
```

In my mind I will end up with something like this: (but this one does not work)

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_datetime
SET value = TIMESTAMP(a.value+300000000)
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime as a on a.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_datetime.entity_id and a.attribute_id = '93'
WHERE attribute_id=94
```

Comment: You question is unclear, show us some sample data and your desired result.

Comment: I added some tables to explain @JPG

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_datetime t1
JOIN catalog_product_entity t2
ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id
AND t1.attribute_id = 94
JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime t3
ON t2.entity_id = t3.entity_id
AND t3.attribute_id = 93
SET t1.value = CASE WHEN t1.value IS NULL THEN date_add(t3.value, interval 1 month)
                    ELSE t1.value END
;
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/552ff/1)